# Integration by parts for 2nd moment of an RV.

Tags: limits, random-variables

Let's suppose I have a continuous random variable X, with cdf $F_X(x)$, ccdf $F^c_X(x)$, and pdf $f_X(x)$. I would like to show that for my specific RV, $$\mathbb{E}[X^2] = \int_0^\infty 2xF^c_X(x)dx - \int^0_\infty 2xF_X(x)dx.$$ This is similar to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3820038/integration-by-parts-in-expectation-of-a-random-variable), using integration by parts, but the problem is that the proof depends on the limiting behavior of $$\left. x^2 F^c_X(x) \right|^\infty_0 = 0.$$ This may or may not be true, as I take it; l'Hopital's doesn't help without having the actual CDF. The limit depends on whether $x^2$ 'overpowers' the convergence of $F_X(x)$ to 1. If $x^2$ goes to infinity faster than $F_X(x)$ goes to 1, this is not true. My question is,
under what conditions is this true? Specifically, **is finite mean and variance of the RV X sufficient?** If not, how could I show that the cdf 'wins' the convergence race?

Edit: It may be helpful to mention that this is inspired by the section 'Calculation from the CDF' of [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance).